# ListDensityPlot controlling the number of colors

Tags: plotting, color

Is there a way to set the number of colors used in ListDensityPlot. 
I am using "Rainbow" as follows:

```
ShowLegend[
ListDensityPlot[TestList, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"],
{ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1] &, 10, 
ToString[LMax], ToString[LMin], LegendPosition -> {1.1, -.4}}]
```

TestList is a list like {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}

In the Legend, to get 5 colors, I can change the 10 above to 5, and I get 5 colors. 
I would like to do the same in ListDensityPlot as well and get 5 colors.
Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks.
Shrihari

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ListContourPlot` confining the contours and you can keep a higher interpolation order:

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/25}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/25}];

ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> 3, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: And then there's that.  (*facepalm*)  +1

Comment: :) your formidable reputation record made me re-read the question a couple of times in case I had misunderstood it...

Comment: Even the best make mistakes.  So, I figure I have to make some too if I aspire to greatness. :^)

Comment: Thanks @gpap for the suggestion to use ListContourPlot instead. That gives a better looking plot.

Comment: However, in ListContourPlot, I get different number of contours for what I think are two equivalent ways of doing it: (1) use the Contours->9 option, (2) Contours->{c1,c2,...c9} where ci are equally spaced. I get 10 colors in (1) as it should, but only 5 colors in (2). Am I missing something?

Comment: If the `ci` don't span the entire range of your function that wouldn't work. Switch off `ColorFunctionScaling` and you'll see what I mean

Comment: I did take the max and min values in the data and computed the equally spaced ci. `In[347]:= {LMax, LMin}
Out[347]= {0.995541,0.792281}
In[348]:= conLst
Out[348]= {0.792281,0.812607,0.832933,0.853259,0.873585,0.893911,0.914237,0.934563,0.954889,0.975215}`. By the way, if I switch off ColorFunctionScaling, it's not what I want at all.

Comment: You're right! I think the difference is that if you use the option `Contours->n` then the midpoint of your data is always a contour. If you equally space the contours manually, then this may not be the case for an even number of contours. I can edit if this isn't clear but try `ListContourPlot[data, 
 Contours -> 
  Table[Round[i, .01], {i, Min@data, 
    Max@data, (Max@data - Min@data)/6}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]` and `ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> 5, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`. They are the same (but for a mismatch in the rounding). Now change the number to 5 and 4 resp.

Comment: Just wonder if you tried the code that you propose?The reason I ask is that the code you just wrote is precisely what I had tried in the first place and found it not to work. For (Max-Min)/n it gives me n/2 colors. I can get n colors for (Max-Min)/2n and that corresponds to Contours -> n.

Comment: Ok, this might be a version thing. I have mathematica 8 and [this](http://twitpic.com/d5uq07/full) is what I get for the above.

Comment: I am using mathematica 8 too. I see for you it works fine. It could be something unique to the data-set I have too. Will check it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To get a limited number of colors you can [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Round.html) the values given to the [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html).
With `Round[#, 1/3]` there will be four values: `{0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}`.

To keep these colors from being blended between regions may require that you don't use interpolation, i.e. set `InterpolationOrder -> 0`.  (Or you could do it *the right way* -- see [gpap](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1079/gpap)'s answer.)

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/25}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/25}];

ListDensityPlot[data,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend["Rainbow", Round[#, 1/3]] &)
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mr.Wizard. I got this to work too, but as you suggest, went with the "right way".